# Converting ASPajax to jquery.ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I trying to convert a ASPajax function to jquery.ajax but without any success.

```
getChapterTit = function(tag){
        ASPajax.LiveASP('getChapterTit("'+tag+'")' , titCallback )
    }
```

the php function is

```
getChapterTit($variable)
```

and returns a value from a table.

I have no clue to to transform this ASP function into a proper jqyery.

Thank you any pointers help.

Comment: What did you try so far? Are you basically just trying to make a jquery ajax request?

Comment: I have tried: getChapterTit = <?php getChapterTit("'+tag+'"); ?> and also $.getScript("ajax.php?value="+ll, function(){}, Its the javascript tag variable that I need to parse to the php script